# Button Click outside of an UpdatePanel causes the panel to refresh

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I have a default VS 2013 ASP.NET Webform project with a master page containing a ScriptManager and a content page containing an UpdatePanel. This is what I have inside the ContentPlaceHolder of the content page:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            Updated at: <%=DateTime.Now.ToString() %>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:Button Text="Click" runat="server" />
</asp:Content>
```

Everytime I click the 'Click' button, the time inside the UpdatePanel gets refreshed, even when I set the UpdateMode to 'Conditional'.

My understanding is that the ASP.NET code to display the time should get executed only the first time I GET the page and subsequently by any triggers defined for the panel(as the update mode of the panel is conditional).

Am I wrong? If so, why?

Comment: This might help: http://forums.asp.net/t/1786512.aspx

Comment: When you click your button out side of UpdatePanel your current page get post back and get re render in browser that's why new date time value is shown. Any postback control out side of UP cases whole page post back and page will re render in browser, Your UP is part of page so it also get re render.

Answer (score 2):

The Button should be placed inside the other update panel.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        Updated at: <%=DateTime.Now.ToString() %>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
             <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                      <asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Click" runat="server" />
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>

            </asp:Content>
```

Hope it helps,

And to know more about update panel please visit the link

http://ajax.net-tutorials.com/controls/updatepanel-control/